# phpExcel: getCalculatedValue() returns #VALUE

Tags: php, phpexcel

Can someone help me with phpExcel Code:

This Codes:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("AF19")->getCalculatedValue();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("AF19")->getFormattedValue();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("AF19")->getValue();
```

Returns:

```
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
=AE19*I19
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: This means expression error, if my memories are correct. `AE19 * I19` results error. Check their values.

Comment: So what are the values of AE19 and I19?

Comment: I19 = 6.03 (Format is on general) and AE19 = 700.00 (Format is on number)

Comment: In that case, all my work over the last 10 years has completely failed to achieve anything.... if the CalcEngine can't even do a simple multiplication without error, then I might as well commit suicide now; but humour me before I open my belly, and run against the debug script that I posted in my answer, and post the results

Comment: PHPExcel is not a native library. So it doesn't have that great integration support.

Comment: @stackplasm - can you explain what you mean by that? native to what? integration with what?

Comment: I was under the impression that PHPExcel doesn't generate XLS in native binary format but it does, so I'm wrong there.

Comment: I used your testFormula function and the result is still the same. But, when I changed the I19 format into number(the same as AE19), it works. But this next story puzzled me, I opened the not edited version of the excel file that I was working on and it happens to produce the result correct result. I wonder??

Comment: The format shouldn't actually make any difference: the calculation engine works on the value contained in the cell, not on its format.... e.g. dates have a value of 46039 but a format of "24-May-2013"

Comment: Ah... It's getting clearer now.  But I still don't get it, why is it showing the result #VALUE. Anyways, it's working now so thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To help debug the problem, run the calculation in DEBUG mode:

```
function testFormula($sheet,$cell) {
    $formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    echo 'Formula Value is' , $formulaValue , PHP_EOL;
    $expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    echo 'Expected Value is '  , 
          ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? 
              $expectedValue : 
              'UNKNOWN'
          ) , PHP_EOL;

    $calculate = false;
    try {
        $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->parseFormula($formulaValue,$sheet->getCell($cell));
        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        $calculate = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($calculate) {
        try {
            $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
            echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->debugLog);
            echo PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->debugLog);
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->writeDebugLog = true;

testFormula($sheet,'AF19');
```

The output from this should help diagnose the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr. Baker

Comment: Thanks for your post. Usefull. In my case, I kept using `getOldCalculatedValue()` and all is working well. I didn't know about existence of this old, but usefull, function.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unsure about the content of a cell (value or formula included), I recommend you to primarily do a check if the cell has a formula and then copy - paste accordingly. getOldCalculatedValue() is very helpful in this case. Here is an example of that:

```
$code = $sheet->getCell('A'.$y)->getValue();
if(strstr($code,'=')==true)
{
    $code = $sheet->getCell('A'.$y)->getOldCalculatedValue();
}
$objPHPExcel4->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
             ->setCellValue('A'.$l, $code);
```

For large data sets, getCalculatedValue() function is really cumbersome and lots of memory will be required to perform correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem, getCalculatedValue() returned #VALUE! on a cell which referenced another cell which contained a formula.

The cause ended up being one of the cells referenced containing a NULL value, even though Excel handled this correctly. All I had to do was add a value of 0 to that cell and it calculated fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try opening up the original Excel file and look at cell AF19. Most likely even MS Excel itself is having trouble calculating the value because of there is something wrong with the formula located at AF19.

It could be that

**This formula is trying to multiply two cells that doesnt contain number**

> =AE19*I19

**AE19 is contains a comma and isn't formatted as a number so PHPExcel sees it as a string**

in such case, you could try formatting the data in excel first by right clicking (in excel) and specify numeric format.

Answer (score 0):

//you can set like this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A20','=AE19 * I19');
```

//because php excel define the code in string so you will get error. because in phpexcel you must use the formula excel. can't make like this A1+A2 or ohters.

**You can multiply in php like this**

```
$bil1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("AE19")->getValue()

$bl2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("I19")->getValue()
```

//the function multiply.

```
$total=$bil1*$bil2;
```

after that you can set the total in you cell

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A20',$total);
```

This is working in my php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of this problem comes when a cell is empty.  When a cell is set to an empty string, some formulas can fail.  Here is an example formula which fails:

`=TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

In order to deal with this "#VALUE!" problem, on a small project I'm setting empty cells to `NULL` instead of `''`.

`$target = ($target == '')? NULL: $target; // without this, empty cells end up being #VALUE! after some formulas`