# How to set cell color based on value using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to export a MySql select and it's working fine.

I know PHPExcel is deprecate and now there is PHPspreadsheets, but it's an old project with an old php version

Anyway, I'd like to color all cells of the sheet based on two value and I am trying with this function code:

```
function cellColor($column, $row){
    global $objPHPExcel;

    $cell = $column.$row;
    $cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getCalculatedValue();

    $color = 'ffffff';
    if($cellValue == 'OK')
       $color = 'ff0000';
    if($cellValue == 'NO')
       $color = '30a30a';

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
             'rgb' => $color
        )
    ));
}
```

Unfortunatelly it's not working. I'm trying to find others solutions online but I don't find anything

Thanks for your help

Comment: On the StackOverflow page [Set Background cell color in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773272/set-background-cell-color-in-phpexcel) there are two ways shown to achieve this: **(1)**  using `applyFromArray`, first answer with `color`, second with `startcolor` (have you tried the first one?) and **(2)** using `setFillType(...)->getStartColor()->setRGB()` (have you tried that? One person there claimed that `applyFromArray` didn't work for him, but this did).

Comment: I saw it, but I didn't find a solution for specific values on the cells. I read about specific cells, but nothing about values. I read wrong? Maybe I didn't catch something

Comment: Can you verify (log) that `$cellValue` indeed contains the excepted values? See the issue faced in [this Stackoverflow question "phpExcel: getCalculatedValue() returns #VALUE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708471/phpexcel-getcalculatedvalue-returns-value).

Comment: I see what you mean with those answers not going into conditional coloring. But you can still try what's shown in the [3rd and 4th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31178566/20594090) instead of your last 6 lines of code as such: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB($color);`.

Comment: I tried but I don't find any solution, unfortunatelly

Comment: "Unfortunatelly it's not working" - in what way? What is the color that is eventually set as the background color for the cell? Is it `ffffff`? What do you get when you replace the `ffffff` with `FF0000`? Will the cell color be red?